# Retornar Struct Dinâmica em Go

Tags: amazon-aws, golang

Como poderia ter um retorno dinâmico em Go utilizando struct ?

Exemplo :

```
func teste() (*struct, err){ 
  type t struct {
  }
  return t, nil
}
```

> O problema é que não gostaria de criar uma struct para cada método que precise retornar algo diferente. Não queria retornar o objeto completo e queria isso da melhor forma, não iria precisar reaproveitar essa struct em local nenhum exceto esse, por isso queria deixar ela dentro da func.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver em pouco tempo após fazer a pergunta. Vou deixar a resposta aqui para ajudar a comunidade.

Exemplo do código que resolveria essa situação.

```
func teste() (struct{name string},error){
  t := struct {
    name    string
  }{
    name:"Mateus",
  }
  return t, nil
}
```

> Dessa forma consegui retornar uma struct dinamica, não precisando assim ter ela criada fora da func.